# SQLAlchemy how to join multiple models in a query

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have multiple models in my flask application that I am trying to perform a join on, but being new to SQLAlchemy this is proving to be somewhat of a headache for me, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have tried

```
def get_item_management(id):  
management_info = FManagementId.query.join(FManagement, FManagementId.id == FManagement.id).filter(FManagementId.id == id).all()
```

and

```
def get_item_management(id):  
management_info = FManagementId.query.filter(FManagementId.id == id).join(FManagement, FManagementId.id == FManagement.id).all()
```

Both return everything that I want from FManagementId matching the input id, but it completely ignores the join.  When inspecting the query that it sent no join is added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the session object and not the base class for this.

```
def get_item_management(id):  
  management_info = session.query(FManagement.id,
                                  FManagementId.id)\
                           .join(FManagementId,
                                 FManagementId.id == FManagement.id)\
                           .filter(FManagementId.id == id).all()
```

Inside the query(), feel free to add any columns from either table that you would like to access.

Comment: @Swisscheese: Could you get your code to work with this?